# How to use memcached in login process cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, caching, authentication, installation, configure

I have installed and configured memcached on our server as per cakephp 3 documentation. Memcached is working fine but I would like to know how to use memcached for login process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new cache configuration for Memcache:

```
Cache::config('sessions', [
  'url' => 'memcached://user:password@cache-host/?timeout=36000&prefix=sess_',
]);
```

You can then configure your sessions to use that config:

```
Configure::write('Session', [
  'defaults' => 'cache',
  'handler' => [
    'config' => 'sessions'
  ]
]);
```

And thats it! you can read more about sessions here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html

Also you can read more about configuring the cache here:

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/caching.html#configuring-cache-class